# Resize TextField and align text top left

Tags: swiftui

I have the following View:

```
struct MemInputFieldView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globalStyles: GlobalStyles
    @State private var memText: String = ""
    @State private var textFieldWidth: CGFloat = .infinity
    @State private var textFieldHeight: CGFloat = 30
    @FocusState private var focusCursorVisible: Bool
    @State private var focus: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            TextField("Type here...", text: $memText, axis: .vertical)
                .focused($focusCursorVisible)
                .frame(width: textFieldWidth, height: textFieldHeight)
                .padding(globalStyles.defaultPadding+4)
                .font(.headline)
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .cornerRadius(6)
                .padding(globalStyles.defaultPadding)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .gesture(
                    TapGesture()
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            focus.toggle()
                        }
                )
                .simultaneousGesture(
                    TapGesture()
                        .onEnded {
                            if focus {
                                withAnimation {
                                    textFieldHeight = 100
                                }
                            } else {
                                withAnimation {
                                    textFieldHeight = 30
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
            Separator()
        }
    }
}
```

In the Preview

[image]

When I tap on the TextField, I see

[image]

How can I align the text top left, or I guess push the TextField height from the top down so the text stays up at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I forgot about frame's alignment:

```
.frame(width: textFieldWidth, height: textFieldHeight, alignment: .topLeading)
```